# android package restarted broadcast not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I am developing an app which needs a broadcast when app opens every time. I had registered the receiver in manifest like this.

```
<receiver android:name="package.broadcast.example" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED" />
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But i cant able to receive the broadcast. I spent 3 hours on this still i cant find wats the mistake. Can anyone refer me the working example of this broadcast. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarted Application/Package does not receive broadcast...

check the following link for details
you can check this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED

Answer (score 0):

do u have the following code which extends BroadcastReceiver, if not than try the following code:

```
         public class AutoConnection extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ((intent.getAction() != null)
                && (intent.getAction()
                        .equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED"))) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Pacakge Restarted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }

     }
```

and in android manifest file add the following code:

```
       <receiver android:name=".AutoConnection" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I changed the code like yours same. But still not receiving the broadcast. Can you please tell when will we receive this broadcast?

Comment: the restarted package does not receive this broadcast. The data contains the name of the package.

Comment: Oh i see, but i want to receive this broadcast in the restarted package, No way to achieve this???