# get view method give null pointer exception in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my Adapter Class :-

```
public class PgListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PgListAdapter.FaqViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Faq> faqList1;
    private ValueAnimator mAnimator;
    private int updatePosition = -1;
    private int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    private int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    private Faq ci;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;
    public static View popupView;
    private Boolean Flag;


    public PgListAdapter(PgList pgList, Context context, List<Faq> faqList) {
        mContext = context;
        this.faqList1 = faqList;


    }





    @Override
    public FaqViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_pglist, parent, false);
        FaqViewHolder vh = new FaqViewHolder(v);

        return vh;


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FaqViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ci = faqList1.get(position);
        holder.questionTv.setText(ci.getQuestion());
        holder.answerTextView.setText(ci.getAnswer());
        holder.Phone.setText(ci.getPhone());
        holder.pgAddress.setText(ci.getAddress());


        holder.ll_top.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

           showFilter();


            }
        });

        holder.Phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + holder.Phone.getText()));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        if (ci.isPGFull()) {
            holder.pgstatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.pgstatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return faqList1 == null ? 0 : faqList1.size();
    }




    class FaqViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private RelativeLayout faqItemView;
        private RelativeLayout extendedView;
        private TextView questionTv, Phone;
        private TextView answerTextView, pgstatus, pgAddress;
        private LinearLayout ll_top;
        private LinearLayout ll_layout1;
        private ImageView arrowImgView;
        private int holderPosition;

        public FaqViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pgPhoneNo1);
            questionTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pgOwner);
            answerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pgPhoneNo);
            pgstatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pgstatus);
            pgAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pgAddress);
            ll_top = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_top);
            ll_layout1 = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_layout1);




        }
    }
```

This is my method to show the PopUpWindow:-

```
public void showFilter() {


        popupView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.pglist_popup, null);

        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


        final TextView tv_phone = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
        final LinearLayout ll_layout = (LinearLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.ll_layout);
        final LinearLayout ll_top = (LinearLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.ll_top);
        TextView tv_address = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        final TextView btn_ok = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);

        // popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
        popupWindow.setFocusable(false);


        tv_phone.setText(ci.getPhone());
        tv_address.setText(ci.getAddress());


        tv_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + tv_phone.getText()));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });


        btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                popupWindow = null;


            }
        });


        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, 0, 0);

    }

}
```

This is my Fragment Class :-

```
public class PgList extends Fragment implements WebServiceListener {


    private String responseCodeCameFromServer = "null";
    private String responseCameFromServer, responseMessageCameFromServer;
    private RecyclerView rvFaqs;
    private List<Faq> faqList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<NameValuePair> basicNameValuePair;
    private GeneralUtilities generalUtilities;
    private SharedPreferencesUtilities sharedPreferencesUtilities;
    PgListAdapter pgAdapter;
    private View rootView;
    private TextView empty_view;
    ProgressDialog br;
    private PgList pgList;


    List<String> typelist = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> citylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<CityAreaDetails> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    Spinner type;
    WebServiceHandler webServiceHandler;


    public PgList() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        if (rootView == null) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pglist, container, false);


            pgList = new PgList();
            generalUtilities = new GeneralUtilities(getActivity());
            sharedPreferencesUtilities = new SharedPreferencesUtilities(getActivity());
            br = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            br.setTitle("Loading...");
            br.setCancelable(false);


            empty_view = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_empty_view);

            empty_view.setText("Sorry for the Inconvience! We will update the list very soon for this Area. ");
            getActivity().setTitle("PG/Room List");
            typelist.add("Boys");
            typelist.add("Girls");
            citylist.clear();
            temp.clear();


            rvFaqs = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.overviewRv);
            rvFaqs.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rvFaqs.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(20, 20, 12));
            rvFaqs.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

             rvFaqs.setAdapter(new PgListAdapter(getActivity(), faqList));
            webServiceHandler = new WebServiceHandler(getActivity());
            webServiceHandler.webServiceListener = PgList.this;
            HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
            formData.put("Type", "Boys");
            formData.put("CityAreaDetailsID", "1");
            if (br != null) {
                br.show();
            }
            //Checking internet connectivity and then requesting to the server
            Log.e("", "Data :" + formData);
            if (generalUtilities.isConnected()) {
                webServiceHandler.requestToServer((getResources().getString(R.string.api_end_point)) + "CityDetails",
                        WebService.ORDER, formData, true);
            } else {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.dismiss();
                }
                generalUtilities.showAlertDialog("Error", getResources().getString(R.string.internet_error), "OK");
            }

        }


        return rootView;
    }
```

When the user click on the recycler view item the popup window showing.but my problem is when user click on the recycler view item and don't press the ok button and click on the back button of the phone so the pop window is showing in the previous activity.i don't want it. i want that when the user click on the back button the pop up window dismiss automatically.please tell me any idea i tried amny method.

Comment: What is inside your **PgList**?

Comment: @RahulSharma please take a look on my code. i want to dismiss the alert dialogue box on the back button click . so i used interface. but the get view method gives the null pointer exception.

Comment: you can dismiss your dialog simply calling **dismiss()** over your dialogbox object. I am confused with your above code.

Comment: ok ! i let you explain. i have a fragment inside the fragment i have a listview on the click of the listview i show a alert dialogue box. but if  i click on the listview then it show the dialogue box but when i click on the back button from the phone it does not dismiss. and showing in the previous activity. i want to dismiss it when i click on the back button.

Comment: ok. Have you used **setCancelable(boolean flag)** when you are opening the alertdialog?

Comment: you don't understand my problem. can you tell me how can i perform action on the back button in fragment.

Comment: I just want to know if you have written **setCancelable(boolean flag)**, just comment this line and run your code.

Comment: @RahulSharma Please see my code. and my question. you understand my problem automatically.

Comment: I have added my answer. Please go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with replacing

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
```

with

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: @LoveAndroid Welcome sir.

Comment: one more thing. if you are free. i am using push notification in my app.its works fine. the notification is coming properly.but when i clean the app from the task manager the the notification is not coming. if you have any idea then tell me plaese.                                                      this is the link of the question :-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488909/ongoing-notification-disappears-when-clearing-memory-from-the-device-in-android

Answer (score 0):

What is PgList? It's a view? Because you need to identify it with an id.

Edit: Normally dialog should close automatically when you press back button, if you didn't override `onBackPressed()` method from activity.
Anyway, you could implement your own listener for dialog, but for the dialog, not entire view:

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {        
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: please let a look on my code. i want to perform action in the override method of the interface. but get view gives the null pointer.

Comment: i tried  this but it did not working.actually i am using fragment and inside the fragment listview is present.and i open the pop up window on the click of the listview.

Comment: How do you instantiate dialog? Update your answer with your code, please.

Comment: @ Florescu George Cătălin Dear sir,please see my updated code and my problem.

Comment: So, if you don't have any internet connection, you show a dialog, right? Here is your problem, no?

Comment: No.it showing the detail of the area as per my project requirement. but when the user click on the ok button the popup window dismiss. and its woorking fine. but if user don't click on the ok button and press the back button then the popup show in the previous activity.that i don't want. so please help me. i am so much frusted for this problem.

Comment: I'm trying. I need to understand your problem. So when user click on back button, current activity is closed and latest one is reopened and the dialog is still there, as i understand your problem. Does the dialog close and reopen or is just staying right there?

Comment: Dear sir, the problem is solved.but thanq for giving me your important time.